# DataFrame to List of OrderedDicts - how to preserve order?

Tags: python, pandas, ordereddict

when converting a `DataFrame` to an `OrderedDict` with `to_dict` and `into` I can't find a way to have it keep the order of the records. Is there a way to do this without looping through the records and converting manually?

```
DataFrame([{"B": 1, "A": 2}]).to_dict(orient='records', into=OrderedDict)
> [OrderedDict([('A', 2), ('B', 1)])]
```

**Update**:
Cannot reproduce outside my debugger. I think that python's pprint module is throwing away the order. that's also how I first started to go down this rabbit hole - I didn't notice that my ordering problem only started after I printed my data to console. I think that VS Code python plugin is also using pprint somehow before showing debug console output, which again throws away order. I'll close this question, very sorry for the wasted time!

Comment: Do you use python 2 or python 3? It looks like the problem is in `DataFrame([{"B": 1, "A": 2}])`, where `{"B": 1, "A": 2}` is a dictionary and in python versions below 3.6 it's not guaranteed to keep the insertion order. So, you end up creating a dataframe that could have the `('A', 2), ('B', 1)` order you see in the final output.

Comment: thank you. it's python 3.8 - so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Interesting. I can't reproduce your problem on python 3.8.

Comment: which pandas version do you have? I have 1.1.2

Comment: I'm trying to guarantee it on the input side, but the more I'm using OrderedDict the more confused I get...

    `in_dict = OrderedDict([('B', 1), ('A', 2)])`
    `print(in_dict)` --> `OrderedDict([('A', 2), ('B', 1)])`

What gives? how else to initialize it with guaranteed order?

Comment: I can't reproduce this last bit with `OrderedDict`.

Comment: it's getting weird - in a VS Code debug console I can reproduce, but in a plain python 3.8 REPL where I only import OrderedDict I cannot. It looks like something in my imports is screwing with my collections :(

Comment: In your VS code debug, if you do `import sys; print(sys.version)` what version do you get?

Comment: it's 3.8 in there as well. I have a hypothesis now what happened: I think that python's `pprint` module is throwing away the order. that's also how I first started to go down this rabbit hole - I didn't notice that my ordering problem only started after I printed my data to console. I think that VS Code python plugin is also using pprint somehow before showing debug console output, which again throws away order. I'll close this question, very sorry for the wasted time!

Answer (score 0):

The key to success is to pass an **initialized instance**, instead of just a class.

Change your code to:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dd = OrderedDict()
result = df.to_dict('records', into=dd)
```

Actually you can get almost the same result with *defaultdict*
(also imported from *collections*):

```
dd = defaultdict(list)
result = df.to_dict('records', into=dd)
```

Comment: Why is that? The [official docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) suggest you can use `into=OrderedDict`,

Comment: The documentation you mentioned contains: *Can be the actual class or an empty instance*. Later *collections.defaultdict* is mentioned with a remark that *you must pass it initialized*. I assumed that the same pertains to *OrderedDict* and it turned out that I was right.

Comment: The official docs explicitly uses `df.to_dict(into=OrderedDict)` as an example, and they explicitly call out that only defaultdict should be initialized. (i.e. `If you want a defaultdict, you need to initialize it`).

Comment: If you think the docs are wrong, maybe it's worth [opening an issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues) in their github